# Calling JavaScript function using specific string

Tags: javascript, calculator, postfix-notation

Is it possible to execute a JavaScript function using specific string?

I am learning JavaScript by programming a postfix notation calculator.

Example: If I write to my input box "5!", I would like `factorial(5)` to be executed or if I write `3nCr5`, execute `ncr(3,5)` etc.

Comment: So you want to execute a function with the value of an input as an argument? Sth like: `fractorial(document.getElementById('id_of_your_input').value)`

Comment: All of it is possible if you code it.

Comment: Who upvoted **this**?!

Comment: List the operations you want to perform and write up parsing rules for them. Once a rule matches, you execute the corresponding function.

Comment: @Dalorzo,*Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.* from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Liam I think the question is fair and it is asking for guidance that is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your objective is to learn Javascript, the way you perform string parsing with JavaScript is using Regular Expression, which by the way it is a separate topic in the whole Javascript world.

For example `"5!"` translated to `factorial(5)` could be achieved by doing something like:

```
var result ="5!".replace(/([\d]+)(!)/g,
   function(match,number,functionType){ 
     if (functionType === "!"){
         return parseInt(number) *2; // perform your math operation here!
     }
  });

console.log(result);
```

[Mozilla Developer website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) has a lot of helpful documentation that can guide you on this and other topics. On the link above your will find an example using RegEx to convert *Fahrenheit degree with its equivalent Celsius degree*, which seems not much different than what you are attempting.

Regarding the Regular Expression used above (**`/([\d]+)(!)/g`**) it can be read as:

**`[\d]+`** match any consecutive numbers that are followed by **`!`**

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great! Just what I needed! Simple and gave me some nice introduction to RegEx. :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It is, although its quite complicated for starter JS. Regular Expressions are a very powerful tool, but not something i would recommend for a beginner, they are quite painful to look at! Practically you would have to make a few considerations. For starters a separator would be necessary to make it easier to separate the parts and accurately read an individual function. A simple space would do for this.

You can then split the parts into an array, and loop the parts through an interpreter function that detects functions and variables.

Something to get you going:

```
var stack = Array(); /* Stack array for calculation */
var result; /* output init */

/* get string from HTML element */
var foostring = document.getElementById("htmlelementID").value; /*  "5 !"  */

/* split string into array using space as the separator */
var fooarray = foostring.split(" "); /* ["5","!"] */

while(i<fooarray.length) 
{
    /*calculation loop */
        if(!isNaN(fooarray[i])) /* input is number, add to stack */
        {
            stack.push(Number(fooarray[i]); /* make sure we convert from string to number before storing */
        }
        else /*input is function, pop required variables from stack and calculate*/
        {
            switch(fooarray[i])
            {
                case "!":
                    var input = stack.pop();
                    var sum = factorial(input);
                    stack.push(sum);
                    break;
                default:
                    console.log("Syntax Error! "+fooarray[i]);
                    return;
            }
        }
        i++;
}

if(stack.length === 1) 
{
    alert("Result: " + stack.pop());
}
else
{
    console.log("Syntax Error! Too many items on stack at complete");
}

/* math functions */

function factorial (n) {
  if (n == 0 || n == 1)
    return 1;
  if (f[n] > 0)
    return f[n];
  return f[n] = factorial(n-1) * n;
}
```

I know very little about postfix, this is based on a pseudo algorithm @ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation

Functionally appears correct but its not tested. You will need to expand the switch case with all the other functions you require, but pay attention to the layout of the example case i put in! Use stack pops to remove the variables from the stack and stack pushs to add the result back to the stack and dont forget the break at the end of each case.

Welcome to JS!  =)

Comment: `"5!".split("");` produce this same result `["5","!"]`  no space needed to split

Comment: Your right that it works in this case but not all functions or variables are single characters in this syntax, hence why a space is needed to properly separate the components

Comment: Then in those situations you use Regex instead with things like [\d]+ = getting numbers only, etc.

Comment: I thought .split() would read a little easier for a beginner, it also allows for a more complication proper reverse polish markup such as "5 1 2 + 4 * + 3 -"